# creating a dropdown list with edit text and a button

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achieve this behavior -

[image]

Where clicking on the arrow expands the layout and clicking again closes the layout

Is there any built in components in Android API's that I can use to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple and  i am telling you because i have done this all you have to play with the visibility of view. Suppose when you are clicking the arrow at that time check whether the drop-down list view is visible or not and if it is visible then make the visibility gone and if it is not visible then make the visibility View.Visible also you will find lot of animation to make it more attractive.Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```java
private static final String[] texts = new String[]{
    "text1","text2", "text3"
};

yourText.setText(texts[0]);
yourText.setOnClickListener(view -> {
     PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
     for (String s : texts) {
         p.getMenu().add(s);
     }
     p.show();
     p.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
         yourText.setText(item.getTitle().toString());
         return true;
     });
});
```